# Trouble uploading videos to Onedrive

Tags: nokia-lumia-735

I need to free up space on my phone (Lumia 735) plus perform a factory reset but I have only just realised my videos were not set to automatically upload to Onedrive. I have now set them to upload but I'm trying to upload earlier videos and they just keep failing the upload. I've also tried connecting phone to pc but again trouble uploading to pc. I'm worried about loosing precious videos of my daughter as a baby.

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: What was the trouble when transferring the files to your PC?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your phone is charged before trying to upload. Windows Phones pause uploads when the battery is low. Also, try using a Wi-Fi network to do the upload. That should do the trick